# Buy key word audio data set

Tags: dataset, audio-recognition

I am trying to implement  audio recognition that can sport key words. I came across [google speech dataset](https://storage.cloud.google.com/download.tensorflow.org/data/speech_commands_v0.02.tar.gz) but it has a limited data set.

Is it possible to buy a new keyword data set ? Can you guys suggest few websites ?

Comment: Try to look in [Open Speech and Language Resource](http://www.openslr.org/resources.php):
Also you can try [Linguistic Data Consortium](https://catalog.ldc.upenn.edu/search)